# How to set Xcode simulator to programmatically rotate to landscape for iPhone/iPad through Selenium

Tags: java, ios, xcode, selenium, appium

Looking at the Appium log it is saying that it is in landscape mode, and landscape shows up in the desired capabilities e.g.:

```
[debug] [XCUITest] Setting initial orientation to 'LANDSCAPE'
```

Currently doing this to set this:

```
descap.setCapability("orientation", "LANDSCAPE");
```

Doing this I am able to get the app to show up in landscape. But how to get the XCode simulator device to display in landscape?

Using Java and Selenium, how do I tell Appium/XCode simulator to display the device in landscape mode? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To display the device in **landscape** mode you can use the following line of code:

```
descap.setCapability("--main-frame-resizes-are-orientation-changes", "landscape");
```

**Note**: Ensure that **`descap`** is an instance of **`ChromeOptions()`** class.

Comment: This is XCode emulator not the Chrome browser

Answer (score 0):

According to [Screen Orientation in Appium](http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2016/01/screen-orientation-in-appium-android.html) the following line should be all you need:

```
driver.rotate(org.openqa.selenium.ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE);
```

Comment: Tried this. It only rotates the app not the device.

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:
    [NSNumber numberWithInteger: UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait]
        forKey:@"orientation"];
```

Comment: Would this rotate the device and not the app? If the device, how to hack this using selenium? I am not an app developer, just a tester.

Answer (score 0):

Allright, I simply use the following to rotate the app:

```
driver.rotate(ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE);
```

or as a capability:

```
capability.setCapability("orientation", "LANDSCAPE");
```

This is all I did code wise. To rotate the actual device I did the following:

```
Open Simulator App > Hardware > Rotate Device Automatically
```

This should cause all of your device to rotate in whatever direction you rotated the app, as long as the option is selected. It won't reset itself on startup or anything so just make sure to not uncheck it.

Comment: Not looking to rotate the app. Looking to rotate the device programmatically.

Comment: Have you tried the last step I mentioned, because this is what you want.

Comment: It is not, I am looking for a programmatic solution not a manual one.

Answer (score 0):

Appium is tool for automating the app not the simulator. In appium you can change app orientation only. If your requirement is like [this](http://xcodetips.com/tips/cmd-left-rotate-simulator.html),you can change orientation of your simulator to landscape or portrait mode use **Cmd-Left** or **Cmd-Right**. This will change the simulator orientation.

Comment: I'm not looking to do it through Appium per se, just looking to do it using a programmatic solution. Keyboard shortcuts I don't believe will work.

Comment: If you just need to test the app in simulator in landscape mode, **Cmd+Left** is the suitable solution. If you are running the simulator on the Mac, you can use the Hardware > Rotate Left | Rotate Right menu. Additionally, the keyboard shortcut is ⌘← for Rotate Left and ⌘→ for Rotate Right.

Comment: Again, not looking for keyboard shortcuts or manually orienting the device. As I've stated many times already, I'm looking for a programmatic solution.